# Confusing PHP bitwise NOT behavior

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

In PHP, if I run the following simple program

```
$number = 9;
var_dump( ~ $number );
```

my output is

```
int(-10)
```

This is confusing to me.  I *thought* `~` was the bitwise `NOT` operator.  So I was expecting something like.

```
if binary 9 is     00000000000000000000000000001001 
then Bitwise NOT 9 11111111111111111111111111110110
```

Meaning `~9` should come out as some ludicrously large integer like `4,294,967,286`.

What subtly of precedence, type coercion, or something else am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like it's being returned as a signed number, in which case -10 is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is defaulting to a signed int - wrap it in decbin to get a binary representation.

Consider:

```
$number = 9;
var_dump(  bindec(decbin(~ $number)) );
```

With [two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the [MSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) of a signed binary number becomes 0-MSB, but every other bit retains its respective positive values.

So for argument's sake (an 8-bit example),

```
Binary 9: 0000 1001
Inverse:  1111 0110
```

This results in `(-128) + 64 + 32 + 16 + 4 + 2 = -10`, so PHP is calculating correctly, its just applying two's compliment to the MSB.

Comment: +1 for good information, but I'm not sure I follow that — are you saying it's being correctly  converted to 11111111111111111111111111110110, and then to 4,294,967,286, but because of integer wrap around it ends up at -10?