# Why is the "NOT" bitwise operator showing output -1 or negative in PHP?

Tags: php, bitwise-or, bitwise-not

I am checking bitwise **NOT** operator including **OR** in Php but don't get why the output is -1. Is there anyone who can explain why the output is 1 of the following code?
Thanks in Advance

```
$x = 15;
$y = 3;

echo $x | ~$y;

Output: -1;
```

Comment: What do you think it should output, and why?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754198/confusing-php-bitwise-not-behavior

Comment: Dear Barmar, I have tried this on my console and got this result. I am learning Php and following the bitwise perception of not and or operator, it seems to me it will be 15 as it is not included the bit of y.  Please, can you explain?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for sharing. I understood it.

Comment: Look at the values of `15` and `~3` in binary. Then combine them with bitwise-OR.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks again @Barmar